# Finding imported data in a cell to stop importing it VBA

Tags: vba, excel, import, connection

Im making a macro on excel that import data from MySQL (with querytables.add and using OBCD) and every time i run the macro it creates a new connection and its a waste of time and space. Is there a function to know if a cell/sheet has a connection on it so i dont have to import the data again and create a new connection or a code to know when was the last time the connection was refreshed.

i looked up for something but it seems there is nothing like it, so maybe and alternative way to do it will be useful, thanks!

Code:

```
Worksheets("Hoja1").Activate

Dim sqlstring As String
Const connstring As String = "ODBC;DSN=blabla;UID=blabla;PWD=blabla"

if "***Range("A1") has a connection***" then
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Conexión").Refresh 'actualize the connection previously made
Else 'import the table from sql server
    sqlstring = vbNullString
    sqlstring = "SELECT * FROM ExTable WHERE year > '2012'"
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=Range("A1"), Sql:=sqlstring)
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just built and tested this nifty little procedure that checks if a connection exists for a specific worksheet range and if so, refreshes it. I also left a spot to  add the part where it creates a new one if it's not found.

*Warning - as written, this will potentially fail if there is another connection listed on the worksheet outside the desired range and it checks that connection first while there is also an existing connection within the desired range. You'll need to adjust for that.*

```
Sub RefreshMakeConnection()

Dim cnT As Connections
Set cnT = ThisWorkbook.Connections

Dim sWS As String
sWS = "Hoja1"

Dim cn As WorkbookConnection

For Each cn In cnT

    If cn.Ranges(1).Parent.Name = sWS Then

        With Worksheets(sWS)

            If Not Intersect(.Range("A1"), cn.Ranges(1)) Is Nothing Then
                cn.Refresh
            Else
                'code to create new connection
            End If

        End With

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This seems what i was looking for, but im new at this so i dont understand the "cn.Ranges(1)", does it took the value of the cell(1,1) of the connection "table"?, assuming the connection made is a table imported on the sheet

Comment: @AEPImiranda `cn.Ranges(1)` produces the area of cells currently covered by the connection. You can check this by using a `debug.print` on `cn.Ranges(1).Address`. It will show the range area for a table, or pivot table for example.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may find the connections name?

```
Sub test()
Dim ItemConnection As Variant
Dim TotalConnections As Connections: Set TotalConnections = ThisWorkbook.Connections
    For Each ItemConnection In TotalConnections
    MsgBox ItemConnection.Name
    Next ItemConnection

End Sub
```

PS: Variant is because I didn't find a way to declare connection as a single item of connection

Comment: The simpler the better right? However, don't forget to upvote and/or check the green mark for the best answer you received -I see quite a few useful ones now :) -